# The tag <ReactComponent> is unrecognized in this browser

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm going some test with jest, I'm currently testing component which using svg. I'm using `ReactComponent` to display my svg as react suggest us to do.

When I'm launching my test I always have this message :

> Warning: The tag  is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.  at ReactComponent

So my code Look like this :

```
import React, { ReactElement, useState } from "react";
// SVG;
import { ReactComponent as Play } from "../../../../../../../../assets/svg/PLAY.svg";

export interface IComponentProps {
  valueX: valueX;
  color: string;
}

export default function Component({
  valueX,
  color,
}: IComponentProps): ReactElement {
  const [state, setState] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
     <div className="wrapper-lesson-video">
      <div className="display-colum">
        <div
          className="pickgradient"
          style={{
            background: `linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, ${color} 100% )`,
          }}
        >
          <img
            alt="title"
            src="https://cdn.xxxx.com/photo/xxxx.jpg"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="launcher-wrapper">
          <div className="launcher-menu">
            <h1 className="secondMinor uppercase">
              {valueX.last}.{valueX.current} {valueX.title}
            </h1>
            <p className="secondMinor m-t-20">{valueX.time}</p>
            <div
              className="major-button center-elements m-t-20"
              onClick={() => setState(!state)}
            >
              <div>Button</div>
              <div
                className="cursor-pointer svg-lesson"
                style={{ fill: "white" }}
              >
                <Play width="30px" height="30px" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the following code is part of my test

```
  function initWrapper(initStore, props) {
    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={initStore}>
        <MemoryRouter>
          <Router>
            <Component {...minProps} />
          </Router>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
    return;
  }

  it("Run index is ran", async () => {
    initWrapper(storeFullyFill, minProps);
    expect(wrapper.find("Memo(component)").length).toBe(1);
    expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

One of my svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="current" height="current" viewBox="0 0 30 30" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>ICONS/PLAY</title>
    <defs>
        <polygon id="path-1-play" points="0 0 9.75 6.19051525 0 12"></polygon>
    </defs>
    <g id="ICONS/PLAY" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="current" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Rectangle-play" transform="translate(10.000000, 9.000000)">
            <mask id="mask-2-play" fill="current">
                <use xlink:href="#path-1-play"></use>
            </mask>
            <use id="play-mask-1" fill="current" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#play-1"></use>
            <rect fill="current" mask="url(#mask-2-play)" x="-10" y="-9" width="30" height="30"></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Do you thing this is temporary warning that'll be fix ? or can I do something to fix / mute it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock SVG files as jest struggles with SVG for some reason.

Create a `__mock__` folder. The directory should be adjacent to node_modules. The setup should be:

**svgrMock.js:**

```js
//__mocks__/svgrMock.js
import * as React from 'react'
export default 'SvgrURL'
export const ReactComponent = 'svg'
```

**package.json**

```
  ...
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.svg": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/svgrMock.js"
    }
  },
```

Just bear in mind only the following are valid methods for importing SVGs after this fix:

```js
import logoURL from '../assets/logo.svg'
// and
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../assets/logo.svg'
```

Full details: https://react-svgr.com/docs/jest/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/hyperfuse/react-anime/issues/33):

For those finding this issue coming from other projects:

This can be fixed by adding `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` to any offending SVG element, including `<g>`, `<use>`, `<text>`, or `<tspan>` (doesn't break spec, but does pollute attribute list).

You could also run tests in something other than `__DEV__` mode, or add the is attribute (breaks HTML spec, requires test selectors to be rewritten).

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/993ca533b42756811731f6b7791ae06a35ee6b4d/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMComponent.js#L442

Comment: I tried ```xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ``` on every tag of my svg but noting to do I still got the same warning...